# Making a transaction lock a row for reading on MariaDB

Tags: transactions, mariadb, isolation-level

I'm having some trouble with ISOLATION levels and a transaction running into a race condition problem.

I have a table with a status field, and n-processes accessing it. Each transaction should return the oldest row with status = 1, and change the status to 2. In theory, 2 process should not be able to get the same registry. But that is not happening. Since the row is not locked for reading by the transaction.

Below you can find a pseudocode of what the transaction will do:

1. Start transaction;
2. Get the oldest row (order by date_created) with status = 1;
3. Update the row and set status = 2;
4. Commit the transaction;

The race condition happens between 2 and 3. Because the row is not locked for selects. is it possible in MariaDB? Playing with isolation levels? What would be the cost of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it all in a single UPDATE statement, e.g

```
 UPDATE table SET field=value,.., status=2
  WHERE status = 1
  ORDER BY date_created DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

There is also SELECT FOR UPDATE, if you need to do something fancier.

Comment: The UPDATE would not be enough because I need to return the row to my code. But the SELECT FOR UPDATE should work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may speed up the query enough to help avoid the lock:

```
INDEX(status, date_created) -- in this order.
```